# Emacs -- sort - usefulness of side effect modifying initial list

Tags: emacs

Is there any usefulness of the side-effect of the function `sort`, which modifies the initial list?  The modified list is different than the result of `sort`:

```
(let* (
    (initial-list '(3 2 4 1))
    (sorted-list (sort initial-list '<)))
  (cons initial-list (list sorted-list)))
```

Would it not be better for the function `sort` to internally use something similar to `copy-list` so that the initial list is not altered?

---

**EDIT**:  Because the community that monitors the Emacs tag of `superuser.com` has expressed a disinterest in responding to this question (e.g., by voting to close it), I created a new Emacs bug report on this issue:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18837

Comment: You should ask and answer this question on the new [Emacs Stack Exchange Site](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `sort` assumes that the initial list is disposable and it leaves said list in an unusuable state.  The following is a workaround that leaves the initial list unscathed:

```lisp
(defun lawlist-sort (seq predicate)
  (let ((disposable-list (copy-list seq)))
    (sort disposable-list predicate)))
```